# Prove that there are at least 2 students taking all 4 classes? Pigeon Hole Principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Within a grade, say that $20$ people are taking math, $23$ are taking biology, $29$ are taking economics, and 31 are taking communications. If there are $32$ people in the grade, prove that there are at least $2$ people who are taking all $4$ classes.

I would really appreciate any help on this, I've been adding all the individual class counts and then dividing by the number of people in the grade, but I don't think that's the proper way to prove it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we add all the students in each class we have $103$ enrollments. Now if all $32$ took exactly three classes each, the maximum that can be obtained without someone taking four classes, we would only have $32 \times 3 = 96$ enrollments. So if we minimize the number of students required to take four classes we still need at least $7$ students to take four classes. Since $7 > 2$ the result follows.

Comment: thank you SO much

Comment: Good solution.  But you only need $2$ students taking all $4$ classes in order to produce $8$ enrollments.

Comment: @awkward That's right but I've already assumed that all students are taking three classes so it would only add one enrollment to the total when we count the fourth class, otherwise we'd be double counting their enrollment to the first three.

Comment: You're right, my mistake.

Comment: @awkward No problem. I initially made the same mistake myself so it happens to the best of us.